# Is it possible to reference a Model defined in another application?

Tags: django

I have to port a relatively large application to Django. This application is composed by a number of components mostly unrelated to each other; but all relate to a common model (i.e. table) called *Location*.

Since each component is itself composed by dozens of models, it seems wiser to encapsulate each of them in its own Django app. However, they all must reference the *Location* model somehow. I am contemplating a folder structure like:

```
/site
 /main
   models.py (contains Location class)
 /componentA
   models.py (references Location class with ForeignKey)
 /componentB
   models.py (references Location class with ForeignKey)
```

Is this possible? Would there be a better strategy to encapsulate these application components? Or must I define the whole schema in a single app with a single `models.py` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your django apps are treated as python modules, so you can set up the model relationship via imports like so:

in main/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    # etc...
```

in componentA/models.py or componentB/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from main.models import Location

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    #etc...
```

Alternatively, according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), you can avoid importing it at declaration time, which may be desirable depending on the size of your project and the number of other dependencies, by writing your dependent model like so:

```
from django.db import models

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey('main.Location')
    #etc...
```

It's a good idea to keep separate concerns separate in your project structure in such a way that different apps do different things--so if you're able to keep the different components separate, that's usually the better design and helps keep your code modular.

Comment: This is the most elaborate answer and posted by the user with lowest reputation. It feels only right to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use models from other apps, like so:

```
from componentB.models import ClassComponentB
```

Where `ClassComponentB` would be some class in the componentB/models.py

Comment: Two equal answers posted at the same time, this should be pretty obvious. Unfortunately, I can only accept one.

Comment: Mine was 2 seconds earlier, but I'm not too worried about it either way ;P

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do an import from that location such as this:

```
from componentA.models import model
```

From there you should be able to do whatever you need.